# Delayed release (no specific date after successful review) AppGallery Connect

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I've found only 2 options in Huawei developer console i.e release after the review and set specific date for the release. But I want 3rd option - a button to make a release after the review.

May be I've not found it?

[image]

Comment: You mean that you want after finishing the review, you click the button to release the app? :)

Comment: Yes, changing release date is a bit "crutch" and inconvenient. In google i can send it for review and after review publish or set specific date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-release_app#h1-1585212100380), you can set the release date for your app. You can release your app at a specified time (accurate to seconds). If your app has been approved and the specified release date has not arrived, you can still **change the release date**. [Changing the release date](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-release_app#h1-1585212201245) does not require manual review. :)